# Async Validator, where api returns a 404 in case of false. Angular4

Tags: angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { AService } from "app/a/services/a.service";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
selector: 'app-a',
templateUrl: './a.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./a.component.css']})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private aService: AService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.addEditAForm = new FormGroup({
        'name': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required],this.ValidateNameAsyn)
});

validateNameAsync(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
 return Observable.timer(500).switchMap(() => {
        return this.aService
            .nameExists(control.value)
            .map(result => (result ? { nameExists: true } : null));
    });
}
```

**AService**

```
nameExists(name: string) {
    let url = BaseApiService.urls.a + '/name=' + name;
    return this.http.get(url, this.baseApiService.setOptions(this.userService.userAuthToken()));
}
```

This is my code, where i am creating an async validator validateNameAsync for a reactive form control.
I haven't been able to test whether it works, because the api returns a 404 if the name doesn't exists and the object if it does.
My question is, is it possible to handle such response in this case? if yes then how?
Thanks

Comment: I believe that should be possible. You will have to use the resolve() / reject() function to return the result of the validation.

Comment: @SonuKapoor, thanks for the reply. So you mean promises instead?

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought, but take a look at this example and see if it helps you: https://kahlillechelt.com/asynchronous-validation-with-angular-reactive-forms-1a392971c062

Comment: I would actually do some change event in this case, checking the value, not formcontrol like Yakov already suggested. Custom validators could be fired several times, at least on component initialization several times, so it makes unneccessary requests. Therefore just a change event would be better in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a better control of an async validator, don't use it as prescribed by Angular doc. Write a validator function that takes a value of the control as an argument and not a FormControl. This way you can handle an HTTP request that validates the value as any other HTTP request and use the catch() operator to handle 404.

Take a look at this code sample where I have two async validators: the first one uses FormControl but the second (in ngOnInit) doesn't. https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/Angular4/form-samples/src/app/async-validator

I could have added a catch() operator there, and in case of 404, I'd have set the validation error like "Can't validate ssn because of the server issue".

Comment: thank you that helped heaps. Just added catch operator to handle 404.

Comment: hey @yakov, do you think if it's ok to return 404 from server if object by such parameter wasn't found?